# Do an $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist, such that $\left(f \circ g\right)'\left(x\right) = \left(g \circ f\right)\left(x\right)$?

Tags: calculus

That is:

$\left(f \circ g\right)'\left(x\right) = \left(g \circ f\right)\left(x\right)$
$\frac{d}{dx} f\left(g\left(x\right)\right) = g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$
$g'\left(x\right) \cdot f'\left(g\left(x\right)\right) = g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$

But that's as far as I can take it.

An obvious solution is $f\left(x\right) = 0$ and $g\left(x\right) = 0$, but do any non-trivial solutions exist?

Comment: Haha, I honestly didn't even think of that. I've edited the post to say that I'm looking for some non-trivial solutions :)

Comment: $f=g=$an iterative quare root of $\exp$ would work ...

Comment: There are still more nonzero functions but trivial examples, such as $g=$ identity function, $f=$ exponential function.